# Wordpress migration not working on live site

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a local wordpress instalation on my system . 
In my system's /etc/hosts file I have an entry for my website 
        127.0.0.1  mysite.com

My website is working fine on my local machine . But the moment i deployed it to online server its dashboard is not working as expected . Problems am facing are :
-- edit page is not opening 
-- not able to open theme custmisation page 
-- not able to install any new plugin 
-- many more as i start to work on dashbord .

I had gone through this link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
but it didnot woked for me .

I also used search and replace db (http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) but it also dont work . Because there is not a single string in my whole db which points to localhost .

My question is what am doing wrong . Am not able to figure out how can it work on my system but cannot work in live environment even if every thing is same ( even the url ). Am trying to fix this issue from last 10 days but with no success .

And one more thing i would like to add is that frontened is working perfectly without any flaws on live site . Only issues am facing are with wordpress dashboard .

Comment: export full db sql file from localhost, edit it using texteditor, replace every instance of localhost with server path (domain+/directory), import the sql on server db

Comment: How did you migrate to production?  Did you copy the entire codebase (including WordPress core and your theme) in addition to a database export/import?

Comment: yes, i had copied everything (including wordpress core and my theme to the server) .

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

1. Export full database to sql file from localhost.
2. Open sql file with some text editor and replace all occurencies of
   localhost with your domain name.
3. Copy all your website files to FTP.
4. Import your previously exported and edited sql file.
5. Change credentials in wp-config.php
6. Edit URL's in .htaccess to match your domain (replace localhost with your domain name)

Comment: Well if there is no entry of localhost in your db, then there should be 127.0.0.1 (based on info you provided). Replace that with your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

1. import Local Database to online server.
2. change the config file and make a connection to the online server.
3. last most important point. check the below link and click this link/button (Problems? Try v 2.1.0 STABLE) for downlode a file for replace a all local site link from the database.

[link](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

After downloading this file please put this file into root of the server and execute/run this file and replace local sever path to online server path.

and last check the database table wp_options field (option_name = siteurl). if site url is change then your site is working fine on the online server...